# Register custom function in hibernate6 and call functions in nested manner

Tags: java, spring-boot, querydsl, spring-boot-3, hibernate-6.x

How to register nested function using FunctionContributor. I am using a function in querydsl like below:
Expressions.simple template(String[].class,"array_remove(array_agg({0}),{1})")

If I register array_remove and array_agg functions separately using functionContributor in hibernate 6, the above nested function might not work

I tried to register the two separate functions. But it is jdbc mapping not found.